# PHP datetime difference in months return bad values, mis php configuration or a bug

Tags: php, date, datetime, diff

So im using in my script datetime and diff method for months difference calculating, and i create test script to show you what is my problem.

Runing on my server (remote linux and local windows in home, timezones Europe/Warsaw):

```
echo "StartDate\tEndDate\tMonthNum\tDifference\n";
for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++){
        $filters['date_from'] = "2020-$i-01";
        $filters['date_to'] = date("Y-m-t", strtotime("2020-$i-01"));
        $datetime1 = new DateTime($filters['date_from']);
        $datetime2 = new DateTime($filters['date_to']);
        $difference = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
        $end = $difference->m;
            echo "{$filters['date_from']}\t{$filters['date_to']}\t" . $i . "\t$end\n";
}
```

and result's with PHP 7.1.29 and PHP 7.4.1:

```
StartDate       EndDate MonthNum        Difference
2020-1-01       2020-01-31      1       0
2020-2-01       2020-02-29      2       0
2020-3-01       2020-03-31      3       1
2020-4-01       2020-04-30      4       0
2020-5-01       2020-05-31      5       1
2020-6-01       2020-06-30      6       0
2020-7-01       2020-07-31      7       1
2020-8-01       2020-08-31      8       0
2020-9-01       2020-09-30      9       0
2020-10-01      2020-10-31      10      1
2020-11-01      2020-11-30      11      0
2020-12-01      2020-12-31      12      1
```

so as you see diff showing 0 or 1 moth difference, 1 if month have more than 30 days, and 0 if less.

So i tested this code on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ and result's are diffrent:

```
StartDate   EndDate MonthNum    Difference
2020-1-01   2020-01-31  1   0
2020-2-01   2020-02-29  2   0
2020-3-01   2020-03-31  3   0
2020-4-01   2020-04-30  4   0
2020-5-01   2020-05-31  5   0
2020-6-01   2020-06-30  6   0
2020-7-01   2020-07-31  7   0
2020-8-01   2020-08-31  8   0
2020-9-01   2020-09-30  9   0
2020-10-01  2020-10-31  10  0
2020-11-01  2020-11-30  11  0
2020-12-01  2020-12-31  12  0
```

All month's have 0 months difference so it's working good, maybe somone know what can be the problem over my server?

Comment: It's not consistent, January and August have 31 days but their difference is still 0

Comment: yes you right, but problem on my server's still exists, and it's sad :(

Comment: If it's any consolation, it's not just your server. https://3v4l.org/jKc3s shows the problem too. I think you've found a PHP bug. It seems to be dependent on the number of days in the previous month; the `diff` is computed relative to that month's number of days, so in March, since February has 29 days, the difference of 30 days comes out to 1 month and 1 day. You can see this if you look at the debugging output of the code at that link. But if you run the same code on your sandbox link, it works exactly as it should...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a bug. The difference from the first day of the month to the last day of the month (00:00) should always return 0 month, because the last day is missing. 1 month is from the first day of the month (00:00) to the first day of the following month at 00:00.
The error is caused by an incorrect time zone shift to UTC. The months are calculated correctly if the time zone UTC is used as a workaround.

```
$tz = new dateTimeZone('UTC');
for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++){
  $n = $i+1;
  $dateFrom = "2020-$i-01";
  $dateTo = $n == 13 ? "2021-01-01" : "2020-$n-01";
  $diff = date_create($dateFrom,$tz)->diff(date_create($dateTo,$tz));
  echo $dateFrom." to ".$dateTo." = ".$diff->m. " month or ".$diff->days." days<br>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
2020-1-01 to 2020-2-01 = 1 month or 31 days
2020-2-01 to 2020-3-01 = 1 month or 29 days
2020-3-01 to 2020-4-01 = 1 month or 31 days
2020-4-01 to 2020-5-01 = 1 month or 30 days
2020-5-01 to 2020-6-01 = 1 month or 31 days
2020-6-01 to 2020-7-01 = 1 month or 30 days
2020-7-01 to 2020-8-01 = 1 month or 31 days
2020-8-01 to 2020-9-01 = 1 month or 31 days
2020-9-01 to 2020-10-01 = 1 month or 30 days
2020-10-01 to 2020-11-01 = 1 month or 31 days
2020-11-01 to 2020-12-01 = 1 month or 30 days
2020-12-01 to 2021-01-01 = 1 month or 31 days
```

Comment: Are you going to file a report?

Comment: No. I think it is already known. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79452

Comment: Yeah, looks pretty much the same issue.